# How can I display a HTML file in app.post method in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var port = 3000;
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Im fine");
});
app.get('/about' ,(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'modalbox.html'));
    res.end();
})
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log(`server running in https://localhost/${port}`);
})
```

modalbox.html isn't serving in "localhost:3000/about"
I can't find, why this html file isn't serving in this link, plz someone gimme the answer

trying to server the html file, but can't serve the file

Comment: Hi,  what is error message? You are using `app.get`, not `app.post`

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: The question is POST but the code is using GET.

Problem 2: Using `res.end()` end the response immediately while the file is being sent. `res.sendFile` is enough.

```
app.post('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'modalbox.html'));
})
```

Problem 3: You've already serve static file using `app.use(express.static(__dirname))`. Just hit `localhost:3000/modalbox.html` and you can see your file